# controller doesn't work in ui-router

Tags: angularjs

I have this home state in my router config,

```
.state('home', {
  url: '',
  controller: 'addMovieCtrl',
  views: {
    "frontpage": {
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_frontpage.html',
      // controller: 'addMovieCtrl'
    },
    "movieoverview": {
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_movieTemplate.html',
      // controller: 'addMovieCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

I want both my views to work with the `addMovieCtrl` controller, but if I assign the controller in the state (like in the example above) the controller doesn't get called.

When I assign the controller in the view (which I now have commented out) it does get called, but I'm pretty sure I should be able to asign a controller to a state and that adds the controller to all the views. Right?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to assign a controller to each view. So, your commented out code is the right way to do it.

```
views: {
    "frontpage": {
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_frontpage.html',
      controller: 'addMovieCtrl'
    },
    "movieoverview": {
      templateUrl: '../assets/angular-app/templates/_movieTemplate.html',
      controller: 'addMovieCtrl'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yea I just figured something out. The controller I assign in the state only applies to the templates inside that state. And not to the views. That doesn't makte a lot of sence to me though.

Comment: Ya, I agree. There should be a way around it. But, for now, your commented out code, is the way to go.